# Response.Addheader Refresh results in 404 error

Tags: c#, asp.net, httpresponse

In a C# web application I use `Response.Redirect("HR.aspx")` and it works with no issue.
However, when I'm trying to redirect after a timeout using `Response.AddHeader("Refresh", "3;url=HR.aspx")` I receive:

> Server Error in '/' Application. The resource cannot be found

Browser URL changes to:

> localhost:1621/HR.aspx,%203;url=HR.aspx

I tried `Response.AddHeader("Refresh", "3;url=~/HR.aspx")` too.

Comment: remove **~/** and check

Comment: @sanjayradadiya it was my first try. Same results

Comment: Response.AddHeader("Refresh", "3;url=" + HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri.Replace(HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.PathAndQuery, "/") + "HR.aspx");

Comment: @sanjayradadiya 'HttpException (0x80004005): A potentially dangerous Requset.Path value was detected from the client (:)'

Comment: whats your URL path pattern ?

Comment: @sanjayradadiya complete url. using visual studio to debug. Server.transfer and response.redirect works

Answer (score 0):

The same happend to me, but I look in the response set and I found that Refresh Header was  added 2 times in the response set, so I remove all refresh values with Response.Headers.Remove("Refresh") and then add Response.AddHeader("Refresh", "60;url=MyUrl.aspx") [here is an image of my problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mbMEB.png)